# Are duplicated answers OK?

Tags: discussion, answers

Are answers that are exact / almost exact duplicates OK? And answers that are partial duplicates (all of new answer is just a subset of older one) OK?

I don't mean situation when both answers are few minutes apart. I mean situations like [in this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5951/is-there-a-drupal-api-function-to-get-the-list-of-nodes-by-type) - Lowest voted answer is from 2013-07-26 10:36:39 and is a duplicate of D7 part of highest voted one posted 2011-06-27 06:28:57 so they are not minutes, but years apart. That's only example, I've seen it more than once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only difference I can see, between those two answers, is that the more recent gives a link to the documentation for the Drupal 7 function. Apart that is not saying something new that was not already said. Probably the user is used to forums, where it can happen that multiple users says the same thing.

If the user added that in Drupal 7 another method should be used, that would have made a good answer, but that is not what the user did. Also, answering about Drupal 8 would have been a good idea, since the question doesn't use any Drupal version tag.

I am going to delete the answer, asking the user to first check if the answer has not been already given. I added the following comments to the answer:

> Welcome to Drupal Answers! Please check if the answer you are going to write was not already given; you are not adding anything to what already said from the answer with the higher score. Stack Exchange sites are not forums; a new answer should be added if there is something new to say. Hint: The second argument of `node_load_multiple()` is deprecated, and Drupal 7 code should be different.

> If you agree with the given answer, you can up-vote it, which is the Stack Exchange way of agreeing about an answer.

Comment: I sure hope you meant "I am going to delete the **answer**", not "I am going to delete the **question**". And what are your general directions in cases like this?

Comment: If the answer is given months apart like in this case, and it doesn't add anything to what already said, the answer is not helpful at all. We don't need 2-5 users saying all the same thing. If the user wanted to say that he agrees on the given answer, that user should have up-voted the question.

Comment: I agree with that. I meant "what are your directions for people that *see* duplicated answers?" Flag? Downvote? Ignore and move on?

Comment: Oh. `:)` If we were a site like Stack Overflow, I would say down-vote it; 20K users can then delete the answer. Since there aren't much 20K users on DA, I would say leave a comment, and flag it for moderation attention after 5-7 days.